# Add only number from two string of data

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make a list from the following data:

```
Ramesh CUB 10000
Rajesh IndianBank 20000
Ramesh CUB 20000
Arya ICICI 200000
Ramesh ICICI 20000
Rajesh KVB 30000
Vimala SBI 3000
Vimala YesBank 200000
Rajesh IndianBank 2000
```

such that Money from strings with same name and bank is added to get:
Expected Output

```
Ramesh  CUB 40000
Ramesh ICICI 20000
Rajesh  IndianBank  22000
Rajesh KVB 30000
Arya ICICI 202000
Vimala SBI 33000
Vimala YesBank 200000
```

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: so you want to group and sum? take a look at [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) (before grouping you need to sort the data tho), or use the equivalent with `pandas` (which may be actually simpler)

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: There are many possible ways to solve your problem ! Providing more context on your data and what you want to achieve, what you already tried could provide a more suitable response.

**Proposition with pandas**

If your data is contained in a file or a string one can see it as a `pandas.DataFrame` and use it's power :

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

pd.read_csv(StringIO('''Ramesh CUB 10000
Rajesh IndianBank 20000
Ramesh CUB 20000
Arya ICICI 200000
Ramesh ICICI 20000
Rajesh KVB 30000
Vimala SBI 3000
Vimala YesBank 200000
Rajesh IndianBank 2000
'''), sep=' ', header=None).groupby([0,1]).sum().reset_index()
```

Explanations :

1. I transform the string in `StringIO` to make it readable by `pd.read_csv`
2. I read the data
3. I groupby the first two columns doing a sum

And the result is :

```
0   Arya    ICICI   200000
1   Rajesh  IndianBank  22000
2   Rajesh  KVB     30000
3   Ramesh  CUB     30000
4   Ramesh  ICICI   20000
5   Vimala  SBI     3000
6   Vimala  YesBank     200000
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a list of elements where every element is like `(x,y,z)` where for example `x = "Ramesh"`, `y = "CUB"`, `z = "10000"`.

After that you have your list then order by alphabetic order for the first element with the function:

```
your_list.sort(key=lambda x:x[0])
```

0 is the index that refers to your x values

If you want to order regarding the z then change 0 with 2

Comment: how will this group or sum the values?

Answer (score 0):

Given a string like this:

```
>>> txt
Ramesh CUB 10000
Rajesh IndianBank 20000
Ramesh CUB 20000
Arya ICICI 200000
Ramesh ICICI 20000
Rajesh KVB 30000
Vimala SBI 3000
Vimala YesBank 200000
Rajesh IndianBank 2000
```

You can create a dict as a counter and add the entries of splitting the lines into key, values:

```
di={}
for s in txt.splitlines():
    b,n=s.rsplit(maxsplit=1)
    di[b]=di.get(b,0)+int(n)

>>> di
{'Ramesh CUB': 30000, 'Rajesh IndianBank': 22000, 
 'Arya ICICI': 200000, 'Ramesh ICICI': 20000, 
 'Rajesh KVB': 30000, 'Vimala SBI': 3000, 
 'Vimala YesBank': 200000}
```

Then rejoin into a string if so needed:

```
>>> print('\n'.join([f'{k} {v}' for k,v in di.items()]))
Ramesh CUB 30000
Rajesh IndianBank 22000
Arya ICICI 200000
Ramesh ICICI 20000
Rajesh KVB 30000
Vimala SBI 3000
Vimala YesBank 200000
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple OOP solution :

```
# some fake data
data = [
    "Ramesh CUB 10000",
    "Rajesh IndianBank 20000",
    "Ramesh CUB 20000",
    "Arya ICICI 200000",
    "Ramesh ICICI 20000",
    "Rajesh KVB 30000",
    "Vimala SBI 3000",
    "vimala YesBank 200000",
    "Rajesh IndianBank 2000"
    ]


class Account:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.transactions = {}

    def add_transaction(self, trans):
        
        bank_trans = self.transactions.get(trans.bank, False)

        # if threre is no transaction for this bank
        if not bank_trans:
            bank_trans = []
            self.transactions[trans.bank] = bank_trans

        bank_trans.append(trans)

    def show_transactions(self):

        for bank in self.transactions:

            total = 0
            for trans in self.transactions[bank]:
                total += trans.value
            
            print(f"{self.name} {bank} {total}")

class Transaction:

    def __init__(self, bank, value):
        self.bank = bank
        self.value = value


def split_info(trans_data):

    accounts = {}

    for data in trans_data:
        name, bank, value = data.split(" ")

        account = accounts.get(name, False)

        # if there is no account
        if not account:
            account = Account(name)
            accounts[name] = account
            
        # make transaction for this bank
        trans = Transaction(bank, float(value))

        # add to accounts records
        account.add_transaction(trans)

    return accounts

def accounts_preview(accounts):

    for account in accounts.values():
        account.show_transactions()
        print("------------")
        
# get the extracted info
accounts = split_info(data)

# show each info
accounts_preview(accounts)
```